# What is the best way to ingest/index markdown documents into Elasticsearch (in order to exploit their data)?

Tags: elasticsearch, markdown

I've created a lot of markdown files with my knowledge.

- one way, to produce some pdf from them,
- another way, to benefit from *Elasticsearch* indexation

for that last part, I've added to the title, chapters, the `abstract:` and `keywords:` entries in the `header-includes:` of my markdown files.
I hope that if an *Elasticsearch* analyzer comes upon my documents, it will make the most of them.

To illustrate, my markdown files are starting that way:

```
---
header-includes:
  \input{apprentissage-header-include}
  \input{apprentissage-include}

title: "Territoire\n  30. Les services publics"
subtitle: "Règles de financement et montages"
date: "03 Mars 2023, version 1.1"

abstract: |
   Modes de financement publics, semi-publics et privés, et montages.  
   L'on fait appel aux SPIC et EPIC pour une Obligation de Service Public (OSP) réclamant un fort investissement ou expertise.  
   SPIC ou EPIC peuvent choisir FCTVA ou Impôt sur les Sociétés (IS).  
   Il faut des règles pour passer en DSP.

keywords:
   - Service Public Administratif (SPA)
   - Service Public Industriel et Commercial (SPIC)
   - Délégation de Service Public (DSP) : affermage, concession
   - Mode de gestion
   - Règle de financement
   - Subvention d'équilibre
   - Obligation de Service Public (OSP)
   - Budget Général ou Budget Annexe (BA)
   - Etablissement Public Industriel et Commercial (EPIC)
   - FCTVA ou Impôt sur les Sociétés
   - Régie directe
   - Régie indirecte
   - Régie intéressée (aux résultats)
   - Marché Public (MP)
   - Association
   - Partenariat Public Privé
   - Mise en concurrence
   - Société Publique Locale (SPL)
   - La Société d'Economie Mixte (SEM)
   - Groupe d'Intérêt Public (GIP)
   - Procédure de passation en Délégation de Service Public
   - Cahier des charges
   - Concurrence
   - Entretien des équipements
   - Risques réels justifiant une Délégation de Service Public (DSP)

author: Marc Le Bihan
geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
---

---

# I) La définition du service public

La définition du service public, comprend :

   - l'objet du service
   - son mode de financement
   - ses modalités de fonctionnement

\bigbreak

Les services publics peuvent être traités :

   - en \definition{Régie} par la collectivité locale
   - ou en \definition{Délégation de Service Public (DSP)} dans les cas où elle n'a pas : 

     - l'expertise
     - la technicité
     - la capacité de sécurisation
     - le savoir faire nécessaire, en général  

      C'est souvent le cas dans le/la :
      
      - environnement (déchets, eaux usées)
      - distribution d'eau potable
      - transport public
      - stationnement (extérieur ou souterrain)
      - restauration (écoles, crèches...)
      - équipements sportifs et culturels

# II) Les règles de financement : SPA, SPIC...

## 1) le Service Public Administratif (SPA)

est typiquement en régie :

   - financé par des taxes, subventions d'équilibre
   - depuis le budget général ou régie
   - par le contribuable
   - FCTVA
```

But I don't know what is the best analyzer (or parser ?) to introduce into *Elasticsearch* my markdown files.

Or is there a *logstash* plugin for that? Yet, I've found none.

---

Continuing my searches over the Internet, I've found this:

[MD-TO-ES (Markdown to Elasticsearch)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-es) : *Module to index your markdown data to Elasticsearch*.

It is for *node.js*, and I don't have a lot of knowledge of it.
I don't know also the worth of that plugin, but it's a beginning. Making me hoping that I can find some other tools.

Comment: Hi Marc, I don't think you will find anything out of the box ready for your use case. Although Markdown is a simple enough language the structure varies a lot from user to user.

I believe you should tell us a bit more about the goal and the issue you are facing.
As a first step, how about indexing it raw ? How bad does it perform ?

Comment: @Paulo The `abstract:`, `keywords:`, etc. I'm using are documented and used by other markdown files creators. However, if the condition is "_use a specific markdown format, like Commonmark_" it's ok. But indexing raw text has no interest for me, for two reasons: 1) I would have to remove all the keywords and their contents first before ingesting plain text only, 2) markdown keywords have the interest of putting some weight to some words or sentences or to choose them to be representative of the whole content. I won't divert from the objective of my question: ingesting a markdown file.

Answer (score 0):

*(I enter this answer not as a final answer, but for the current solution I'm using yet)*

Eventually, I'm wondering if it's really clever to attempt to index the markdown file itself, instead of its pdf transformation.

- The main risk is that characters that are represented by keywords, such as those being between `$ ... $` for *Latex* or symbols, won't be resolved and well taken into account. Example: `$\rightarrow$` could be red verbatim, instead of: `→`
- a `pdfinfo` command shows me the availability of some keywords declared into the markdown header:

```bash
pdfinfo t131-responsabilite_penale.pdf
```

```
Title:           t131. Responsabilité pénale
Subject:         
Keywords:        marchés publics, gestion de fait, comptable de fait, transparence, favoritisme, conflit d’intérêt formel, potentiel ou réel
Author:          Marc Le Bihan
Creator:         LaTeX via pandoc
Producer:        pdfTeX-1.40.24
```

Therefore, it seems to me more easy to ingest/index the pdf itself.

I have to adapt myself. I don't see the `abstract:` keyword in a markdown header taken into account in the pdf info, but the `subject` and `keywords` are. And the resulting *Elastic* index looks promising enough:

```json
{
  "_index": "apprentissage",
  "_id": "t131-responsabilite_penale",
  "_version": 2,
  "_seq_no": 12,
  "_primary_term": 6,

   "attachment": {
      "date": "2023-09-24T09:19:58Z",
      "keywords": "marchés publics, gestion de fait, comptable de fait, transparence, favoritisme, conflit d’intérêt formel, potentiel ou réel",
      "content_type": "application/pdf",
      "author": "Marc Le Bihan",
      "format": "application/pdf; version=1.5",
      "modified": "2023-09-24T09:19:58Z",
      "language": "fr",
      "title": "t131. Responsabilité pénale",
      "creator_tool": "LaTeX via pandoc",
      "content": """t131. Responsabilité pénale
  "found": true,
   [...]
  }
}
```

---

For convenience, my markdown to pdf *Pandoc* conversion script is (I use it with an alias `gen`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export source=$1

# Le paramètre source doit être alimenté
if [ -z "$source" ]; then
   echo "Le nom du fichier markdown à convertir en pdf est attendu en paramètre." >&2
   exit 1
fi

# Il ne doit pas contenir d'extension
if [[ "$source" == *"."* ]]; then
   echo "Le nom du fichier markdown à convertir en pdf ne doit pas avoir d'extension (.md ou autre)." >&2
   exit 1
fi

conversion=$(pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml --metadata-file=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/metadata.json --include-in-header=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-header-include.tex --include-in-header=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-include.tex "${source}".md -o "${source}".pdf)

if $conversion; then
   echo "Markdown ${source}.md converti en ${source}.pdf"
fi;
```

and the one to ingest the pdf content to *Elastic 8.x*, this one (I use with an alias `index`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export source=$1

# Le paramètre source doit être alimenté
if [ -z "$source" ]; then
   echo "Le nom du fichier pdf à indexer dans Elastic est attendu en paramètre." >&2
   exit 1
fi

# Si le fichier source n'a pas d'extension, lui rajouter celle .pdf
if [[ "$source" != *"."* ]]; then
   source=$source.pdf
fi

# Il doit avoir l'extension pdf
if [[ "$source" != *".pdf" ]]; then
   echo "Le fichier à indexer dans Elastic doit avoir l'extension .pdf" >&2
   exit 1
fi

host="http://localhost:9200"
user="elastic"
pwd="mypassword"

index=apprentissage
entree=$(basename "${source%.*}")
json_file=$(mktemp)
cur_url="$host/$index/_doc/$entree?pipeline=attachment"

echo '{"data"  : "'"$( base64 "$source" -w 0    )"'"}' >"$json_file"
# echo "transfert via $json_file vers $cur_url"

if ! ingest=$(curl -s -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "$user:$pwd" -d "@$json_file" "$cur_url"); then
  echo "Echec de l'ingestion dans Elastic de $source : $ingest" >&2
  exit $?
fi

rm "$json_file"
echo "$source indexé dans Elastic"
```

I usually type two commands, then, given a `t131-responsabilite_penale.md` markdown:

```bash
gen t131-responsabilite_penale
index t131-responsabilite_penale
```

to index that markdown, as a pdf, into *Elastic*.